# Derive the expected value and variance of $Z$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2.$ Let $$Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}.$$

Derive the expected value and variance of $Z$. Remember to justify all non-algebraic steps.

I thought that I could just plug in the value of $Z$ and find the expected value, but that's not it I don't think. This is just stumping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This smells like homework so I won't post entire solution (although it is almost complete).
\begin{align}
E(Z)&=\dfrac{E(X-\mu )}{\sigma}\\
&=\dfrac{E(X)-\mu}{\sigma}\\
&=?\\
Var(Z)&=Var(\dfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma})\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2}Var(X-\mu)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2}Var(X)\\
&=?
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks so much, I thought that was what I had to do. I just needed to be reminded about the properties of expected values.

Comment: @Caty: If I may point to another feature of this site, if you liked a question or answer, you can upvote it (top left next to the answer/question); and also accept an answer that you liked best. The person having submitted such question/answer will be rewarded with some reputation (which, for many, is part of the fun :) ). For accepting an answer, you also get a few points.

Comment: how did the omega squared term appear in the second line of your Var(Z) solution?